UITextContent type does not always work in SwiftUI
I have an app that requires a few forms with textfields like login, forgot password, create account etc.
My goal is to be able to provide suggestions in these textfields using SwiftUIs textContentType modifier.
I created a custom textfield which could be used as a regular textfield or a secure textfield like for a password and apply some universal styling.
For simplicity sake, here is a simplified version the textfield to demonstrate the problem:
struct CustomTextField: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if viewModel.isSecure {
                SecureField("", text: $viewModel.text)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.gray)
            } else {
                TextField("", text: $viewModel.text)
                    .textContentType(viewModel.textContentType)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.gray)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

The viewModel driving this view:
class TextInputFieldViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text: String
    @Published var isSecure: Bool
    
    let textContentType: UITextContentType
    
    init(text: String,
         isSecure: Bool = false,
         textContentType: UITextContentType) {
        self.text = text
        self.isSecure = isSecure
        self.textContentType = textContentType
    }
}

Now I use one textfield with the contentType set to email, this works well:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: false,
                                                               textContentType: .emailAddress))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


Now if I try to build a login name with an email and password, the email suggestion no longer works:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: false,
                                                               textContentType: .emailAddress))
            
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: true,
                                                               textContentType: .password))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

As you see, no suggestions:

If I build a create account form like this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: false,
                                                               textContentType: .emailAddress))
            
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: false,
                                                               textContentType: .givenName))
            
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: false,
                                                               textContentType: .familyName))
            
            CustomTextField(viewModel: TextInputFieldViewModel(text: "",
                                                               isSecure: true,
                                                               textContentType: .password))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

The first two fields of email and given name give suggestions, but the family name has no suggestions which happens to be before the secure field.
I thought maybe my family name wasn't set up, but this wasn't the case as if I swap the order around to email, family name, given name and password - the given name doesn't show any suggestions.
It seems whatever is the field before the secure text input doesn't show suggestions.
In the CustomTextField, if I remove the if-else logic and just keep a TextField only, this works fine, however, I would like it to work with a reusable view that can work as both a regular and secure textfield.
Any ideas / workarounds to this ?
I need this to support iOS 16+.

StateObject should always be private

Thanks for the suggestion, do you feel that is the issue though ? In my actual implementation, the StateObject is indeed private @loremipsum

Maybe, it depends if it works without it. If you don’t provide an MRE we can’t help

I've provided all the code for a MRE

View is your view model, StateObject is for something else (when you need reference semantics in a State)

@malhal making the view model a State object or even removing the view model and just make the textContentType a State property gives the same result so this is not the issue.

The issue to me seems like a weird SwiftUI bug and happens to be with having a SecureField in the form.
A simple reproducible example of this is below:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("", text: $username)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .background(.gray)
                
            
            SecureField("", text: $password)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .background(.gray)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .padding()
    }
}

This yields no suggestions on the email field.

It seems the secure field impacts the suggestions of the field before it.
However, if I put a kind of dummy / placeholder textview before the secure textview in the view hierarchy that is hidden like so:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            TextField("", text: $username)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .frame(height: 50)
                .background(.gray)
                
            ZStack {
                TextField("", text: .constant(""))
                    .disabled(true)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.clear)
                
                SecureField("", text: $password)
                    .frame(height: 50)
                    .background(.gray)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .padding()
    }
}

The suggestions start showing up:

